# RPM Requires group

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

During RPM installation under the `Requires` section of my spec file how do I install a group of things?  For instance:

```
Requires: Developer Tools
```

which will pull from `yum` because I execute this like so:

`yum install myRpm.rpm`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. RPM used to have a built-in concept of groups (look at `/usr/share/doc/rpm/GROUPS` for the canonical list, still), but this turned out to not be very useful and was dropped. (But even then, there was no way to express requirements in this way.) Now, package groups are done at a higher level in "comps" files understood by yum — but there's no way to refer to them in a package.

Some distributions address this by creating "metapackages" — packages which by their own Requires lines define a sort of group. We don't do that in Fedora (and that's inherited into CentOS and RHEL).

So, basically — you'll have to either document that this RPM requires a certain group to really be useful, or list all of the real dependencies one by one.

Comment: immediate follow up, could I get around this by dropping things in `%pre`?

Comment: @Woot4Moo You mean, like, installing other packages in `%pre`? Not safely, no.

Comment: so kind of, basically I just want to fire off `yum groupinstall Developer Tools` instead of listing off everything in requires or going to the extent of metapackages.  But if that is less correct I will hedge against it.